# Regex - return match between strings in template literals

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all strings between custom string, so here we go:

```
var string = `

    <!--@hello-dear:John-->
    <h1>John</h1>
    <!--@bye-dear:John-->

`;

var startString = "<!--@hello-dear:John-->";
var endString   = "<!--@bye-dear:John-->";

var regString = startString + "(.*?)" + endString;
var regex     = new RegExp(regString, "i");

console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Returns **null**

Expected that matched **object** with the **string**

```
"<!--@hello-dear:John-->
<h1>John</h1>
<!--@bye-dear:John-->"
```

Comment: you will have to regex escape your start and end strings.

Comment: Replace `(.*?)` with `([^]*?)`, or `([\s\S]*?)`, or in the latest Chrome versions (and whichever support ECMA 2018 standard), use `s` modifier.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply !!